# converting a decimal to hex decimal and then to bytes in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, hex, byte

I am trying to convert a decimal number to hex decimal and then to bytes.

for example if i want to convert decimal number 5 to bytes. i use

```
def decimal_to_hexadecimal(dec): 
    decimal = int(dec) 
    return hex(decimal)

id = decimal_to_hexadecimal(5)
```

this gives hexadecimal representation of 5 i.e 0x5

Now i convert it to bytes using

```
id_bytes = bytes([0x5])
```

This works fine but i have to manually feed the hex decimal. so when i try this

```
equipmentID = int(equipmentID)
equipmentID_hex = hex(equipmentID)
equipmentID = bytes(equipmentID_hex)
```

It gives an error

```
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the function you are not converting the hex data to byes.
If you need to convert to bytes, you need to use encoding technique.

```
 equipmentID = bytes(equipmentID_hex, 'utf-8')
```